# oncreateMenuOptions is not getting called from Overide

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an actionbar with a search Icon that when pressed loads a new fragment called search. When this fragment is loaded I want the search bar at the top to expand and open the keyboard so the user can type and search. I have my onCreateOptionsMenu looking like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        Log.d("click" , "inside the on create");

        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2).getActionView();
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
```

All the code for the fragment is:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 2/13/14.
 */

public class Search extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private ListView lv;
    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);


        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);


        //todo: code body goes here





        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;


}


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        Log.d("click" , "inside the on create");

        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2).getActionView();
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }




    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query) {

        //toast query

        //make json variables to fill

        // url to make request
        String url = "myURL";



        try {
            query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String jsonUrl = url + query;



        //todo: get json
        new ReadJSONResult(getActivity()).execute(jsonUrl);

        return false;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }





}
```

***Update:***

Code I added was

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

This is the FC

```
02-13 17:11:11.093  21151-21151/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.Search.onCreateOptionsMenu(Search.java:66)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1868)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:2068)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2567)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:485)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:851)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:786)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:545)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:771)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***Update 3:***

As per the answer below that is trying to help me. I tried this now:

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(android.R.menu, inflater);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

But I am getting this error:

on android.R.menu

```
Expression Expected
```

main.xml is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search2"
        android:title="Search"
        android:onClick="goToSearch"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />


</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the activity your fragment wants to participate in the options menu. Add this in your onCreateView() method:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

**Update 1**:

Your onCreateOptionsMenu method should be:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        Log.d("click" , "inside the on create");

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2).getActionView();
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
```

**Update 2:**

Your main.xml should also needs to declare the action view class:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search2"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"
        android:onClick="goToSearch"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />
</menu>
```

Comment: I added this and it foce closing now with this error:

Comment: added the FC to the question above. I added that line of code to my fragment right?

Comment: Your onCreateOptionsMenu is now definitely being called (you can see it in the stacktrace). Looks like you also need to add a call to super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); on the first line of that method. If you are still getting the null pointer exception after that then double check to make sure there is an ID called "menu_search2" in the layout for your fragment.

Comment: I checked an my main.xml does have menu_search2. I added that one line but get some errors, I posted in the update. I will post the main.xml file too

Comment: No, you need to add that super call on the first line of the onCreateOptionsMenu override, the setHasOptionsMenu call belongs in onCreateView (doesn't matter where).  Also the super call you posted in the update is wrong, it should be super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

Comment: OK I added it right before the setIconified call and it force closes on the same line.

Comment: Updated my answer, notice I also changed the way you were inflating the menu, using the inflater passed into this method.

Comment: Just noticed you also aren't declaring your search menu item correctly, check my updated answer.